# A company produces 16 pots daily and we know that the probability of producing a non-defective unit is 0.4.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution

a) Calculate the probability that the first non-defective casserole is number 3
b)Calculate the probability that strictly before 6 pots some non-defective ones will come out.
c) How many tables must be produced on average to find the first non-defective table?

I have this exercise for my statistic class. The exercise have different questions, but I can't answer these ones and I don't know how to solve it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: "I have this exercise for my statistic class. The exercise have different questions, but I can't answer these ones and I don't know how to solve it."  At face value, this is a very surprising assertion.  In a class, you are exposed to theorems, worked examples, and previously solved problems.  Then, you are given a problem that is typically an application of the theory that you have been taught.  Please see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) on mathSE protocol.

Comment: It is not clear to me how parts (a) and (c) relate to the assertion in the title.